# Setting directory to path of script

Tags: python

What I would like to do is create a variable homedir that is set to the home folder script. How do I do this? Like say the script is located in C:\blah\, I would want homedir to be assigned to that.

```
homedir = (current directory)
pdfList = []

def getfiles():
    directory = os.listdir(homedir)
    for file in directory:
        if "pdf" in file:
            pdfList.append(file)
```

Answer (score 5):

The `__file__` module attribute contains the script location, but it may be relative.  The file below is `c:\test\x.py`.

```
import os
print(__file__)
homedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
print(homedir)
```

Output:

```
.\x.py
c:\test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
homedir = '.'
```

or

```
import os
homedir = os.getcwd()
```

will cause `os.listdir(homedir)` to list the files (and subdirectories) in the current working directory (i.e. the directory from which the script was executed). Note that this is *NOT* necessarily the same as the directory which contains the script. For that directory use

```
import os
homedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```